# Error importing Graph from bulbs.neo4jserver in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, neo4j, gremlin, bulbs

I am trying to run `neo4j` using `gremlin`. I am following one of the first examples in the bulbs documentation, trying to import `bulbs.neo4jserver` .Graph. I can import bulbs, it sees gremlin, but fails to import Graph using the command below.

```
>>> import bulbs
>>> bulbs.gremlin
<module 'bulbs.gremlin' from 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bulbs\gremlin.pyc'>
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Graph
```

I have downloaded and run maven on gremlin and rexster. I am working in Windows 8 with Python 2.7, an Anaconda installation.

What else do you need to know?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: version:  bulbs==0.3.28-201040127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Bulbs are you using?

```
$ pip freeze | grep bulbs
```

You should be able to just do this...

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Feb 19 2014, 13:47:28) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
```